# Debugging a gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have placed a `debugger` statement in one of my gulp tasks.

I have tried the following and it hits the debugger, but the console simply appears to "stop", rather than fall into a debug mode.

```
node --harmony --debug $(which gulp) default
```

What am I doing wrong?